# Define many output files in a loop in c++

Tags: c++, file

I have c++ program in which I am running the same function many times but each time for a different value of a parameter. For each value of the parameter I want to output the result of the function to file whose name contains the value of the parameter. How to do this? Here is an example of what I want to do.

```
for(parameter = 10;parameter<=100;parameter*=10){
       ofstream file("file"<<parameter<<".txt", ios::out);
       function();
       file<<result;
       file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with [`ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
for (int parameter = 10; parameter <= 100; paramter *=10 )
{
    std::ostringstream name;
    name << "file" << parameter << ".txt";

    // If your library is too old, you have to use
    // name.str().c_str()
    // to get the string
    std::ofstream file(name.str()); // or name.str().c_str() in C++03

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Also, if Boost is an option, use `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(parameter)`.

Comment: @ereOn: I see no reason for that, since it uses a similar technique to streams (or even the streams) under the hood.

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::basic_ostringstream<char>::__string_type, const std::ios_base::openmode&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream:697:7: note: candidate is: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]

Comment: the error I get is mentioned in the above comment, however if I simple cout<<name.str() in the loop it prints the filenames, but somehow it is not able to create the file

Comment: Try `std::ofstream file(name.str().c_str());`

Comment: @Xeo: It doesn't use a *similar* technique: it uses the **exact same** technique. It just makes the intent clearer and is more readable than the three lines needed to instantiate a `std::ostringstream`. Definitely not required, but if boost is already used, I see no reason why **not** to use it (the performance loss here, is likely to be unnoticeable obviously).

Comment: @ereOn: Except that you are putting three pieces together while converting one of them. `boost::lexical_cast` may suffice for the conversion part, but the concatenation has do be done by something else then. Either a `std::string` or a `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: @ereOn: Btw, on the edit, I rolled it back since the comment above that line already contained the solution for older libraries. In C++11 (and as such, by many libraries supported already, since it's a backwards compatible change), the file streams indeed have a `std::string const&` ctor.

Comment: @Xeo: That's what I said actually. I'm not sure why you don't like `boost::lexical_cast<>`: the concatenation would indeed have to be done with `operator+()` but again, in this case (creating a file name) I hardly think the performance impact is significant. However, the readability gain is obvious. Regarding the edit: do as you like, but you basically made a correct(ed) answer less portable. Not everybody can use C++11 and the OP hasn't said it was using it.

Comment: @ereOn: I didn't make it less portable (maybe the copy-paste mode), the comment always said what had to be done for older compilers.

Comment: @Xeo: I'm sorry to hurt your feelings, but as it stands, this answer is wrong in a non-C++11 environment. Sure the OP can read the comments, but why do you want to force him to do so when he could just have had a corrected answer directly ? You are not even the answer's author, so I don't quite get it.

Comment: @ereOn: C++11 is the Standard. If you want C++03, then tag it. Else, C++11 is the way it is.

Comment: @DeadMG: Are you saying C++11 is the default on all compilers for all architectures ? Don't get me wrong, I wish that was true, and I would certainly use the `std::string` constructor I was sure the all the target compilers provided it. For all we know, the OP could be working on a not up-to-date compiler and in this context, the answer is less helpful.

Comment: @ereOn: No, I'm saying that it's his job to mention that. If you tag C++, then that is C++11. If you have a non-conformant compiler, then mention it. I can't psychically divine random restrictions.

Comment: @DeadMG: I suppose you are actually editing all old questions incorrectly tagged as `c++` because they are now incorrectly referring to `C++11`, right ?

Comment: @ereOn: What makes you say that? Their tagging was correct as of the time of asking. And some questions *have* been retagged.

Comment: @DeadMG: Glad to see you agree there is no reliable way to guess which standard version an OP is referring to when only `c++` is specified. In the face of ambiguity, I resist the temptation to guess and provide the most widely usable answer if there is one. I can however understand why someone would assume C++11 is meant.